# jquery alert on href of pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

Good evening!
I have a pagination. But my jquery code doesn't run.. I don't understand why... Someone can explain me? thanks
My plan is to realize a transition when I select the page but I tried to put alert at the beginning

```
<div class="filnews">
<?php
    // On récupère les 5 derniers billets
    $req = $bdd->query('SELECT id, titre, contenu, DATE_FORMAT(date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%i\') AS date_creation_fr FROM billets ORDER BY date_creation DESC LIMIT '.$depart.', '.$articlesPage);

    while ($donnees = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {       
        if(($donnees['id'] % 2) == 1){
?> <div class="coulalter1">
<?php

}else{?>
    <div class="coulalter2">

<?php   
}
    ?>




    <div class="news">
        <div class="beaute">
       <a href="commentaires.php?billet=<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $donnees['date_creation_fr']; ?>
            <em> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['titre']); ?>
            </em></a></div></div>

     </div>


    <?php
    } // Fin de la boucle des billets
    $req->closeCursor();
    ?>

</div>    
    <div id="page">
    <?php

    for($i=1;$i<=$pagesTotales;$i++){
        if($i == $pageCourante){
            echo $i.' ';
        }
        else{
            echo '<a href=index.php?page='.$i.'>'.$i.'</a> ';
        }

}
    ?>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page a").click(function(){
        page=($(this).attr("href"));
        $.ajax({
            url: dalilasite.php+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                alert("La page chargée");
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);  
            }
        })
        return false;
    });

});
</script></div>
```

Comment: First: declare your page variable by adding a "var" before your page variable. Then, where does the variable "dalilasite.php" comes from?

Comment: dalilasite.php is the main page which one where is the pagination , I'm wrong? @charlyberthet

Comment: And what is the name of you get parameter used by dalilasite.php to handle the pagination?